# how to avoid Nested qualifier in my c# regex expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use regular expression to validate input such as:

```
aa,bb,c1  or T1
```

basically a comma separated string and each item should be at most 2 character long.

This is what I come up with:

```
^([a-z0-9\s]{2}+,)*([a-z0-9\s]{2}+){1}$
```

I tried in regex101 and it does want I want. However, when I put this into c#, it throws Nested qualifier exception.

I admit that my knowledge of regex is low, can anyone point out what kind of regex expression should I write for c# world?

Comment: NET regex does not support possessive quantifiers

Comment: then what kind of expression should I write for c# in my scenario?

Comment: Just replace `{2}+` with `{2}`. Note `{1}` makes no sense and does nothing in any regex, never use it.